# Find True Wind from ship course and observed wind

Tags: wind

Assume that I am sailing in a ship where I know the course of the ship & speed of the ship and observed wind direction & speed using Automatic Weather Station fitted on mast. I would like to know the formula used for calculating True Wind direction & speed?

I have gone through this link https://oic-nwreviewer.blogspot.com/2014/01/solving-for-true-wind-direction.html which provide some input regarding the formula used. However, the atmospheric wind used in this example is an apparent wind and not the observed wind.

My intention is to write a small program so that True Wind is calculated faster. It appears to be little difficult as there is no proper formula available in the internet.

Comment: I think this is actually a vector math problem, not an Earth Science problem.